# how to access drive as certain google user

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I am using appengine( python) and trying to manage a shared google drive directory for certain user. Can my program always access the drive without to go to authorize page, even when I am login as different user. Say I login 123 but I want to access abc's google drive all the time.

Comment: You need to use OAuth, and you can only access a user's Drive if they authenticated you. However, if you ask for access for the app even when the user is not logged in, and it is granted, I think you can (not sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user adds a app engine project service account as a share, you can always access it, without the OAuth2 dance.

Your app engine project service account looks like : example@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
You can find information here : https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts#google_app_engine_project_service_accounts

```
def _init_service_account(self):

    if os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].startswith('Development') :
        logging.warning('Service account not used in development')
        return None
    else :        
        SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
        API_KEY = '.....'                                 # GAE
        credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope=SCOPE)
        logging.info('service account : ' + app_identity.get_service_account_name())
        http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
        return build('drive', 'v2', http=http, developerKey=API_KEY)
```

Comment: I deployed my app like this. It will try to list all files under a folder id.
 http = httplib2.Http()
        drive_service = build('drive', 'v2')

        folder_id = "XXXX"
        param = {}
        children = drive_service.children().list(folderId=folder_id, **param).execute()

        for child in children.get('items', []):
            content += "File.Id: %s <p>" % child['id']

And I am getting this error: 
HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/XXXXXXXXXXX/children?alt=json returned "Login Required">

Comment: Dit you add the service account as a shared user? 401 means : access not allowed. By the way you cannot use this account in the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through domain wide delegation for Google Apps users: https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation, though the domain admin will have to add your app for authorization.

If you want to create an app for the marketplace which will prevent the need for a manual setup, you can follow instructions here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/tutorial_python_gae#Integrate-OAuth

I don't think you can access any of Google's API if the user is not logged into your application even if you were previously granted access, at least from my understanding of the authentication methods available.

Comment: You can. I use it for accessing Google Drive: https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts#google_app_engine_project_service_accounts

Comment: I'm familiar with service accounts, that's how the delegation method I described works, but what do you mean `add the service account as a shared user` and how do you tell the API you want to list a particular users files?

Comment: The GAE service account is a user. You have to add this user to your files and folders.

Comment: I see, I must have misunderstood the question then, I was trying to explain a method that would work across all files/folders for everyone who added the app, not for a particular file and/or folder that the user would manually have to add the service account to...

Comment: All those users can allow or deny (using Oauth2) an app to access files, when the app request access. A service account is not needed.