# How to access OAuth2 from non-user process

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api, google-oauth

I'm using google's oauth2client library for GAE to access google analytics data from a GAE application. When I hit the URL from a web browser the first time, it got my credentials and made a token. My plan was to then re-use that token in a cron job that runs nightly.

However, that cron job always goes 302, which I assume means that my token is not being accepted. Some code:

```
class GetGAHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
  @decorator.oauth_required
  def get(self):
    if not decorator.has_credentials():
      logging.error("GA is asking for auth. Please visit %s" % self.request.url)
      self.redirect(decorator.authorize_url())
      return
```

(I then do useful stuff after that.)

When I hit that from a browser, it never asks me for my credentials, so I presume the token is just fine. However, when my cron runs, this happens:

```
2013-02-18 20:00:00.224 /admin/getGA 302 10ms 0kb AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)
0.1.0.1 - - [18/Feb/2013:17:00:00 -0800] "GET /admin/getGA HTTP/1.1" 302 426 - "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "kaon-log.appspot.com" ms=10 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000048 queue_name=__cron task_name=ff7194e21b55970ebaf7e369504de801 instance=00c61b117cbe215d928dbc53a31f55fb06f769b5
```

As you can see, there is a 302, but no logging message, so I guess the decorator is doing the redirect.

What am I missing? Accessing OAuth2 APIs from a cron must be something that is pretty common...

Comment: 302 means a redirect. I think for the login.

Comment: Yes, I know that. The question is, if I have a valid token, why does it think I need to log in?

Comment: It looks like the token must be refreshed. To prevent this you can use a app engine service account. But: you cannot use the app engine service account in the SDK and you have to add this account to your analytics. I'am not familiair with the analytics API; I use a project service account to access Google Drive.

Comment: Hmmm. The comments on this page http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/03/service-accounts-have-arrived.html lead me to believe that GA doesn't support this yet, so perhaps I'm screwed.

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940129/how-to-access-drive-as-certain-google-user/14945549#14945549